# Conversion from series to integration and inverse

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

Recently, I created a formula that seems okay but does not work properly.

This is a formula for linking a series to an integral by exploiting an already existing link and brought to light by Riemann.

So here it is :

First, we start from the definition of a Riemann integral and the approximation by squares to find out that

$$\int_a^b \psi(s)ds = \lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\mu} \sum_{k=0}^{\mu(b-a)} \psi\left(a+\frac{k}{\mu} \right)$$
Then, we substitute the $\mu$ constant in the left side and we consider that $a = 0$ and $b = 1$ so that we can then consider that $b-a = 1$

$$\lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \mu \int_0^1 \psi(s)ds = \lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \psi \left( \frac{k}{\mu} \right)$$

Then, we try to make the link between $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(k)$ and $\lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \psi(k/\mu)$. From there, it seems obvious that we have
$$\lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \psi(k/\mu) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(k) \iff \forall s, \psi(s) = \lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \phi(\mu s)$$

So, we can finaly replace by :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(k) = \lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \mu \phi(\mu s)ds$$

Or, after some calculations with, per exemple $\phi(s) = (s+1)^{-2}$ (so that we have $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \phi(k) = \pi^2/6$), we should have $$\lim\limits_{\mu \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{\mu}{(\mu s +1)^2} ds = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$, but calculations shows us that this integral approches $1$ when $\mu$ approches to infinity.

I can't find out the mistake. If you could help me, I would be grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: In your $\iff$, what is $s$? You don't quantify it on the RHS, and it doesn't appear on the left. Should it be "for every $s$?"

Comment: Yes it's for all s

Comment: Most of your expressions are diverging limits. You may not reason on equalities between non-existent limits. And I can't see any justification for the "it seems obvious that" result.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to turn a discrete sum in an integral by mapping the set of naturals to a finite interval (normalized to $[0,1]$) using *a linear transform*. Such a transform does not exist, because these sets have different cardinalities.

A correct correspondence between series and integrals is given by the Euler-Maclaurin formula.